# Does jUnit support following attributes/adnotation?

Tags: java, testing, junit, frameworks, nunit

I need to know please if jUnit is similar to nUnit and provides:
 **multiple attributes**, **expectedexception**, **combinatorial** and **testcase**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Expected exception could be annotated as described in this [JUnit 4 Tutorial: Expected Exception](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-2-expected-exception-test/):

```
@Test(expected = Exception.class)  
public void test() {
    ...
}
```

Multiple attributes, combinatorial and testcases could be covered using parameterized tests: [JUnit4 Tutorial: Parameterized Test](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/).

Comment: JUnit provides better ways for testing exceptions: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Exception-testing